# what is the normal curvature of a straight line on a surface?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

I am unsure of how to think of this intuitively as in visualising it. I think Euler's formula of $ k_n=k_1cos^2(\theta)+k_2sin^2(\theta) $ may help but I'm not sure what the principal curvatures would be of a straight line.

In my book the geodesic curvature of a straight line is shown to be 0 by using k=kn^2+kg^2. I understand that k=0 but not sure why kn^2 is 0?

Comment: How do you define the principal curvatures? Then, take your straight line as a curve $\gamma$ and find the principal curvatures. What do you get? What is therefore the curvature?

Comment: A curve doesn't have principal curvatures !?

Comment: Does this mean normal curvature is 0 ? Because in my book the geodesic curvature of a straight line is shown to be 0 by using k=kn^2+kg^2. I understand that k=0 but not sure why kn^2 is 0? So is it because it's not defined ?

Comment: This definition you mentioned in your post is only used for 2D-surfaces. A line is 1D. Hence this is not defined. If you so badly want to asign a value, it probably should be 0.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course not. I assume they have been taught that. I am trying to make him/her think about the problem...

Comment: @Edu: sorry, I wasn't addressing you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No apologies needed! Your comment is meaningful whether addressing the question or my comment.

Comment: @M.Winter The definition is used for curves on a surface. A straight line may be 1D but it lies in 2D hence it may be used.

Comment: @aprilanalysis: If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a^{2} + b^{2} = 0$, what can you say about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Your formula seems to be wrong. The formula should be: $k^2 = kn^2 + kg^2$.  Not that kn is equal to zero, but kg is equal to zero.